# Sum of antidiagonal of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sum, diagonal

I'm trying to sum the elements along the antidiagonal (secondary diagonal, minor diagonal) of a matrix.

So, if I have a matrix m:

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7), 3)
m

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    1
[2,]    3    2    3
[3,]    1    5    7
```

I'm looking for the sum `m[3, 1] + m[2, 2] + m[1, 3]`, i.e. `1 + 2 + 1`

I can't figure out how to set up an iteration. As far as I know there is no function for this (like `diag()` for the other diagonal).

Comment: This is called the "secondary" or "minor" diagonal.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using

```
m <- matrix(c(2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7), 3)
```

**1)** Reverse the rows as shown (or the columns - not shown), take the diagonal and sum:

```
sum(diag(m[nrow(m):1, ]))
## [1] 4
```

**2)** or use `row` and `col` like this:

```
sum(m[c(row(m) + col(m) - nrow(m) == 1)])
## [1] 4
```

This generalizes to other anti-diagonals since `row(m) + col(m) - nrow(m)` is constant along all anti-diagonals.  For such a generalization it might be more convenient to write the part within `c(...)` as `row(m) + col(m) - nrow(m) - 1 == 0` since then replacing 0 with -1 uses the superdiagonal and with +1 uses the subdiagonal.   -2 and 2 use the second superdiagonal and subdiagonal respectively and so on.

**3)** or use this sequence of indexes:

```
n <- nrow(m)
sum(m[seq(n, by = n-1, length = n)])
## [1] 4
```

**4)** or use `outer` like this:

```
n <- nrow(m)
sum(m[!c(outer(1:n, n:1, "-"))])
## [1] 4
```

This one generalizes nicely to other anti-diagonals too as `outer(1:n, n:1, "-")` is constant along anti-diagonals.  We can write  `m[outer(1:n, n:1) == 0]` and if we replace 0 with -1 we get the super anti-diagonal and with +1 we get the sub anti-diagonal.  -2 and 2 give the super super and sub sub antidiagonals.  For example `sum(m[c(outer(1:n, n:1, "-") == 1)])` is the sum of the sub anti-diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Some of the syntax is beyond me so I'll need to work through you very thorough and well-laid out examples.

Answer (score 5):

This is sometimes called the "secondary diagonal" or "minor diagonal".

Another short solution:

```
sum(diag(apply(m,2,rev)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could index out the elements you want to sum

```
sum(m[cbind(3:1, 1:3)])
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is actually what I was envisioning but couldn't figure out how to write it.  I was fumbling with a nested 'for' loop which obviously didn't give me what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way without using a loop, assuming that your matrix is m:

```
sum(diag(matrix(c(m[,3],m[,2],m[,1]), nrow=3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# setup
m <- matrix(c(2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3, 7), 3)
n <- nrow(m)

# solution
diag(diag(m[n:1,]))[n:1,]
```